# GlassFish Forbidden 403 error page

Tags: java, web-applications, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I am really confused with this error and need some help.

When accessing my link the first time in IE I type in : https://something/other/test.jsp

and I'm presented with the `FORBIDDEN-403 GlassFish Enterprise Server is now Presenting The Forbidden Page` error page in GlassFish.

However, if I refresh this same page then I see the results of `test.jsp`.

I have filters in my java code and all filters are letting test.jsp let go through.

Why am I getting the `GlassFish 403` error page in this scenario? and why does it go away after refresh?

Once I see results of test.jsp...If I close IE and open it again, then again this same thing happens.

Comment: What if you http:// instead of https.

Comment: You may want to look at this page: http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E403.html

Comment: `http://` does not work. `checkupdown` site has good detailed information but i can not find explanation regarding why it works on refresh!

Answer (score 0):

IE is notorious for page-caching. I know this from my experiences with AJAX.so maybe when you refresh the page, it shows you the cached page.